# Accessing large memory (32 GB) using /dev/zero

Tags: linux, memory, mmap

I want to use `/dev/zero` for storing lots of temporary data (32 GB or around that). I am doing this:

```
fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR );
// <Exit on error>
vbase = (uint64_t*) mmap(NULL, MEMSIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, 0);
// <Exit on error>
ftruncate(fd, (off_t) MEMSIZE);
```

I am changing `MEMSIZE` from 1GB to 32 GB (performing a memtest) to see if I can really access all that range. I am running out of memory at 1 GB.

Is there something I am missing ? Am I mmap'ing correctly ?
Or am I running into some system limit ? How can I check if this is happening ?

P.S: I run many programs that generate many gigs of data within a single file, so I dont know if there is an artificial upper limit, just that I seem to be running into something.

Comment: Do you have a 64-bit system? Because in a 32-bit system you will not be able to map 32GB, not even close! More like the 1GB you seem to have.

Comment: I do. I am running on a SLES 64 bit machine

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit I'm confused about what you're actually trying to do. Anyway, a couple of reason why what you do might not work:

1. From the mmap(2) manpage: "MAP_ANONYMOUS
             The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are initialized to zero.  The fd and  offset  arguments  are  ignored;"
2. From the null(4) manpage: "Data written to a null or zero special file is discarded."

So anyway, before MAP_ANONYMOUS, mmap'ing /dev/zero was sometimes used to get anonymous (i.e. not backed by any file) memory. No need to do both. In either case, actually writing to all that memory implies that you need some kind of backing store for it, either physical memory or swap space. If you cannot guarantee that, maybe it's better to mmap() a real file on a filesystem with enough space?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Linux kernel `mmap` implementation:

```
vm_mmap vm_mmap_pgoff  do_mmap_pgoff  mmap_region  file->f_op->mmap(file, vma)
```

1. In the function `do_mmap_pgoff`, it checks the `max_map_count`

   ```
   if (mm->map_count > sysctl_max_map_count)
       return -ENOMEM;
   ```

   ```
   root> sysctl -a | grep map_count
   vm.max_map_count = 65530
   ```
2. In the function `mmap_region`, it checks the process virtual address limit (whether it is unlimited).

   ```
   int may_expand_vm(struct mm_struct *mm, unsigned long npages)
   {
                  unsigned long cur = mm->total_vm;          /* pages */
                  unsigned long lim;

                  lim = rlimit(RLIMIT_AS) >> PAGE_SHIFT;

                  if (cur + npages > lim)
                                 return 0;
                  return 1;
   }
   ```

   ```
   root> ulimit -a | grep virtual
   virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
   ```

   In linux kernel, init task has the `rlimit` setting by default.

   ```
   [RLIMIT_AS]                      = {  RLIM_INFINITY,  RLIM_INFINITY },     \

   #ifndef RLIM_INFINITY
   # define RLIM_INFINITY                (~0UL)
   #endif
   ```

   In order to prove it, use the `test_mem` program

   ```
   tmp> ./test_mem 
   RLIMIT_AS limit got sucessfully:
   soft_limit=4294967295, hard_limit=4294967295
   RLIMIT_DATA limit got sucessfully:
   soft_limit=4294967295, hard_limit=4294967295
   ```

   ```
   struct rlimit rl;
   int ret;
   ret = getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &rl);
   if (ret == 0) {
       printf("RLIMIT_AS limit got sucessfully:\n");
       printf("soft_limit=%lld, hard_limit=%lld\n", (long long)rl.rlim_cur,          (long long)rl.rlim_max);
   }
   ```

   That means unlimited means 0xFFFFFFFF for 32bit app in the 64bit OS. Change the shell virtual address limit, it could reflect correctly.

   ```
   root> ulimit -v 1024000
   tmp> ./test_mem 
   RLIMIT_AS limit got sucessfully:
   soft_limit=1048576000, hard_limit=1048576000
   RLIMIT_DATA limit got sucessfully:
   soft_limit=4294967295, hard_limit=4294967295
   ```
3. In `mmap_region`, there is an accountable check

   ```
   accountable_mapping   security_vm_enough_memory_mm  cap_vm_enough_memory  __vm_enough_memory  overcommit/swap/admin and user reserve handling.
   ```

Please follow the three steps to check whether they can meet.